# Generate dynamic columns and bind data dynamically for WPF Datagrid or DevexGridcontrol

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, devexpress

I have the following data structure:

```
public class StudentScore {
    public string ScoreValue{ get; set; }
}

public class Student {
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    //Scores.Count will be = EndDate-StartDate
    public ObservableCollection<StudentScore> Scores { get;set; } 
}

ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } //Can be changed by user dynamically
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; } //Can be changed dynamically
```

What i am interested to achieve in WPF DataGrid/DevExpress GridControl is as follows:
`Column 1` is always fixed, which is student name and remaining columns will be only based on the number of `Scores` and each row should populate the student name  and scores.

And each cell should have a two way binding where user can edit the score to reflect back in the actual VM property.

[image: STudent poc image]
I tried to set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to true - it generates only two columns because I have only `StudentName` and `Scores` properties. So i need some thing that can generate columns from collection for each row.

Comment: Did the accepted answer really help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind grid columns via the [GridControl.ColumnsSource](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_ColumnsSourcetopic) property.
Please review this approach detailed description in the following help article: [Binding to a Collection of Columns](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10121).

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question as asked. A combobox of dates is not the same as a varying amount of columns.

Comment: Especially that I have a property that is a list of values, which should generate into cells each, but all other properties are cells themself.